# Vue. How to pass dynamic modificator in vuejs custom directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<Button 
  ...
  v-tooltip.bottom="{ value: tooltip, disabled: !tooltip }"
/>
```

How can I change "bottom" dynamicaly?
I have several modifiers: top, left, bottom, right. In a different situation, it is necessary to create a component with only one other specific modifier. Sculpting the rendering condition depending on the modifier seems not to be the optimal solution.

I use [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

Vue does not support dynamic modifiers. However, if you read through the API reference for `v-tooltip`, you will realise that the directive also accepts all component props:

> The directive also support all the component props
> —[source](https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/api/#directive-options)

...which includes placement, so you can technically do this:

```
<Button 
  v-tooltip="{ value: tooltip, disabled: !tooltip, placement: tooltipPlacement }"
/>
```

...where `tooltipPlacement` (or a variable of your choice) can be any of the accepted placement values: https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/api/#placement

Comment: I use [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/tooltip) and it doesn't have API for positioning, only through modifiers. 
Since there is no possibility to dynamically change the modifier, then I will have to use conditional rendering.

Comment: The documentation you've linked clearly mentions the possibility to configure what is being passed into `v-tooltip`, then it's a matter of `<InputText type="text" v-tooltip="{ value: 'Enter your username', disabled: true, placement: SOME_PLACEMENT }" />`

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work. In your case, the hint adjusts automatically. This is equivalent to the absence of a modifier.
`v-tooltip="{ 'Some hint', disabled: false, placement: 'top' }"`

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across the same problem and found the solution under [PrimeVue's GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/2255):

```
<InputText v-tooltip:[{position:dynamicDirectionValue}]="...." />
```

`position` is a key that must be used and `dynamicDirectionValue` should be your variable with the direction as a string.